# How to use 1 statement for many different things?

Tags: sql

I want to do the following for stats, normally, it would be multiple statements commited at one go. Is there a way to make these into 1 statement?

This table will give the stats of API calls by the minute.

```
-------------------------
Statistic
-------------------------
appName varchar(256) PK
timeMinuteMS bigint PK
totalElapsedMs bigint
totalCount bigInt
minElapsedMs bigInt
maxElapsedMs bigInt
```

The statements I want to run are

```
UPDATE Statistic SET minElapsedMS = ? WHERE(appName = ? AND timeMinuteMs = ? AND minElapsedMs > ?);
UPDATE Statistic SET maxElapsedMS = ? WHERE(appName = ? AND timeMinuteMs = ? AND maxElapsedMs < ?);
UPDATE Statistic SET totalElapsedMs = (totalElapsedMs + ?), totalCount = (totalCount + 1) WHERE(appName = ? AND timeMinuteMs = ?);
```

Is there a way to combine all 3 into 1?

I will run the performance test later, just need the 1 statement first.

Comment: Given the three `WHERE` conditions are different I would expect it to be more efficient to run this as 3 separate queries.

Comment: Hi @theAnonymous, what is the database you use ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this in one `update`, but it is quite a bit more complicated:

```
UPDATE Statistic
    SET minElapsedMS = (CASE WHEN timeMinuteMs = ? AND minElapsedMs > ? THEN ? ELSE minElapsedMS END),
        maxElapsedMS = (CASE WHEN timeMinuteMs = ? AND maxElapsedMs < ? THEN ? ELSE maxElapsedMS END),
        totalElapsedMs = totalElapsedMs + (CASE WHEN timeMinuteMs = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        totalCount = totalCount + (CASE WHEN timeMinuteMs = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    WHERE appName = ? AND
          ( (timeMinuteMs = ? AND minElapsedMs > ?) OR
            (timeMinuteMs = ? AND maxElapsedMs < ?) OR
            timeMinuteMs = ?
          );
```

Note that this has more parameters, so you need to be careful about passing the values in.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to keep all three and wrap them a transaction.